# Div set to absolute position not pushing other div down below it

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have a div positioned as absolute and I know that it's meant to not push the div below it down, but how can I do that without using margin bottom, or top for the below div.

I'd like the `.header` to stay with `position: absolute`, but the div below it `.blog` should just stack below it.

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.header {
  background-color: #e9118c;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
.inner-container {
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  width: 1100px;
  display: inline;
}
.search,
.social {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
}
.social {
  text-align: right;
}
.social img {
  width: 35px;
}
.blog {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <title>Christina's Baking Adventure</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:400,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./christinasbakingadventure.css">
</header>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="search">
        search box
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="blog">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <img src="./christinasbakingadventurelogo.png" style="width: 350px;" alt="Christina's Baking Adventure logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do what you want without using absolute? Absolute positioned elements won't change the position of other elements no matter what

Comment: I can't see a solution without using padding or margin..

Answer (score 0):

What if you made the header position: relative and just floated the blog?

```css
    body {
     font-family: Georgia, serif;
    }
    
    .clear {
     clear: both;
    }
    
    .header {
     background-color: #e9118c;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     postition: relative;
     padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    }
    
    .inner-container {
     padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
     width: 1100px;
     display: inline;
    }
    
    .search, .social {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 600px;
    }
    
    .social {
     text-align: right;
    }
    
    .social img {
     width: 35px;
    }
    
    .blog {
     float: left;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <header>
      <title>Christina's Baking Adventure</title>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:400,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./christinasbakingadventure.css">
     </header>
     <body>
      <div class="container">
       <div class="header">
        <div class="inner-container">
         <div class="search">
          search box
         </div>
         <div class="social">
          <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
          <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
          <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
          <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
          <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <div class="blog">
        <div class="inner-container">
         <img src="./christinasbakingadventurelogo.png" style="width: 350px;" alt="Christina's Baking Adventure logo">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change position for .header and .blog, just add top in .blog
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vgrcgnk/)

```
     div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="inner-container">
                    <div class="search">
                        search box
                    </div>
                    <div class="social">
                        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                        <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="blog">
                <div class="inner-container">
                    <img src="./christinasbakingadventurelogo.png" style="width: 350px;" alt="Christina's Baking Adventure logo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
    body {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.header {
    background-color: #e9118c;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.inner-container {
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    width: 1100px;
    display: inline;
}

.search, .social {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
}

.social {
    text-align: right;
}

.social img {
    width: 35px;
}

.blog {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to make simple things hard ;-)

First of all, before you start coding your own clasess and stuff, consider clearing the default values of the most used tags, i.e. set the values of padding, margin, border and outline, etc to 0. For example like this:

```
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
blockqoute, a, acronym, address, big, cite, code, img, q, small, strong, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, table, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

By doing this you will maintain as much control over the elements on your page as possible, and you will avoid many suprises.

Also most of the times you won't avoid using maring/padding - but simply know all the values of those attributes.

Clearing the padding and margin for body tag only will make your header stick nice and easy to the top left corner of the page. No need for absolute position.

```css
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
        blockqoute, a, acronym, address, big, cite, code, img, q, small, strong, ol, ul, li,
        fieldset, form, label, table, tr, th, td {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            background: transparent;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Georgia, serif;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: #e9118c;
/* You don't have to have 4 values. 2 are equal to top-down left-right. */
            padding: 5px 0; 
            margin: 0;
        }

        .inner-container {
            padding: 0 30px;
            width: 1100px;
            display: inline;
        }

        .search, .social {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 600px;
        }

        .social {
            text-align: right;
        }

            .social img {
                width: 35px;
            }

        .blog {
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="search">
                    search box
                </div>
                <div class="social">
                    <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                    <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                    <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                    <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                    <img src="./fb-icon.png" alt="facebook">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="blog">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <!-- I'd recommend not to use inline styles. It's easier to maintain your code when everything is in stylesheet.-->
                <!-- Create for example an id #logo with width set to 350 -->
                <img src="./christinasbakingadventurelogo.png" style="width: 350px;" alt="Christina's Baking Adventure logo" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```